# Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc

I'm using SQL Server 2014 in my local system. There is an MVC application with .NET Framework 4.6.1 and it worked fine.

Now, I've created a new MVC application with .NET Framework 4.7.2 and see this issue. The local website is unable to connect to the Database.

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException   Cannot open database "NewApp"
> requested by the login. The login failed. Login failed for user 'IIS
> APPPOOL\dev.newapp.com'.

I have checked the User Mapping properties and both applications are listed. I did not make any changes in IIS or the SQL Server.

Also, I tried changing the Identity in IIS for DefaultAppPool to LocalSystem with no luck.

The IIS, SQL server & the website - all are in the same machine.
[image]

[image]

Comment: could you add a bit more details about your infrastructure please? is the SQL server and IIS running on the same machine, different machines, different domains...?

Comment: @user7415753 all are on the same machine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There a difference between Windows and SQL Server Authentication.

Per your images you have configured `sa` user which is SQL Server Authentication and you cannot use Windows Authentication in your application and **web.config**.

So, if you want to use `sa` login then update your **web.config** file and database connection string to be like:

`Server=yourServer;Database=yourDatabaseName;User=sa;Password=saPassword;`

or different syntax:

`Data Source=yourServer;Initial Catalog=yourDatabaseName;User=sa;Password=saPassword;`

Your application is trying to use local user as Windows authentication.

Comment: I could resolve the issue by setting `Integrated Security=false` in the connection string. Earlier it was set to true.

Comment: Yes, Integrated Security=true is forcing Windows Authentication.